# How to create a multi variable date range plots with plotly

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I have the following dataset

```
Date, IMEI
22-7-2017, I
23-7-2017, I
24-7-2017, I
25-7-2017, I
26-7-2017, C
27-7-2017, C
28-7-2017, C
29-7-2017, C
30-7-2017, C
31-7-2017, A
01-8-2017, A
02-8-2017, A
03-8-2017, A
04-8-2017, I
05-8-2017, C
06-8-2017, A
07-8-2017, A
07-8-2017, A
08-8-2017, I
09-8-2017, I
09-8-2017, A
09-8-2017, C
```

and i want to create an interactive plot to visualize it using plotly to allow the user set the date range manually in "R Shiny" using a dateRangeInput function in r shiny, I've tried the following but still getting wrong plot

```
ui = fluidpage(
 sidebarPanel(
dateRangeInput(inputId="myDateRange", label="", start = NULL, end = NULL, min = NULL, max = NULL),
))
mainPanel(
plotlyOutput("")
)
 server = function(input, output, session) {
output$age <- renderPlotly({
               plot_ly(a1, x= a1$Date, y = a1$IMEI)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reproducible example.

First, make sure your `Date` column in your data is a `Date` object.

Your `ui` needed minor edits, including capital "P" in `fluidPage` and adjustment of parentheses. Your `plotlyOutput` needed an "InputId" - looks like you want to use `age` based on `server`.

Next, in `server` you can subset your data based on the `dateRangeInput`. There are 2 values `input$myDateRange[1]` and `input$myDateRange[2]` - corresponding to the lower and higher limits of the input chosen. You can subset your data and include rows of data where `Date` is between those values.

Otherwise, I selected some example settings for `plot_ly` to use.

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, format = "%d-%m-%Y")

library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui = fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    dateRangeInput(inputId="myDateRange", label="", start = NULL, end = NULL, min = NULL, max = NULL),
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotlyOutput("age")
  )
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
  output$age <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(
      data = subset(df, Date > input$myDateRange[1] & Date < input$myDateRange[2]), 
      x = ~Date, 
      y = ~IMEI,
      type = "scatter",
      mode = "markers")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this plot is what i meant to create, 
I did not know i have to subset data in order to do so.
Thanks man

Comment: Glad to help. If appropriate, please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) regarding what to do when someone answers your question on SO,

Comment: I tried to vote up since you answered my question but I got this message 
"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: You can try to “accept” the answer instead.